# How to fill text of a child with the background-image of the parent?

Tags: css, css-transitions, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

### The Problem

Well ... i don't know if this is even possible. I have a *wonderful* menu with a gradient and their child elements with transparent background-color and color white: https://nimb.ws/o5xWlZ

In the hover, i want to make the background-color of this child element color white and the color text make it transparent for **show that part of gradient**.

### What I Have Tried

My first reaction was:

```
child-element{background-color:#fff;color:transparent}
```

And you can imagine the results( SPOILER: https://nimb.ws/TNrCKJ ) ... only white in the button.
Then, i think to apply a box-shadow ...

```
 child-element{-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 300px 200px rgba(255,255,255,1);-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 300px 200px rgba(255,255,255,1);box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 300px 200px rgba(255,255,255,1);}
```

And wel.. searching and searching ... doesn't find anything ... so, here i am.

### The Code

This is the HTML, i can't editing so much, because is a dynamic `<ul>` in a .tpl

```
<div id="block_top_menu" class="full-width here-is-the-gradient">
    <ul class="sf-menu transparent">
        <li class="menu-li category transparent"><a href="/257-productos-medicos" title="Productos Médicos">Productos Médicos</a></li>
        ... others li elements ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
#block_top_menu{
    background:#6aa447;background:-moz-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);
    background:-webkit-gradient(left top,right top,color-stop(0%,#6aa447),color-stop(100%,#4d81bd));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);
    background:linear-gradient(to right,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6aa447',endColorstr='#4d81bd',GradientType=1);otherthings
}
.sf-menu{
      background:transparent;
   ...otherthings...
}
...
.sf-menu > li > a{
       border:none;color:#fff;
       font: 500 18px Oswald;
       padding:10px 5px;
       text-transform:none;
 }
.sf-menu > li > a:hover {
   /* What do I put here? */
 }
```

### An example:

Like to fill text with an image as in Photoshop:

[image]

Thanks you very much for the time :)

Comment: Looks like somethng LESS or SCSS could help you with. Google these.

Comment: You want to create an effect where the text color appears to be part of the gradient? Like a cut?

Comment: @EdwinDijasChiwona yes, exactly, like a cut, like this ![Example](https://3v6x691yvn532gp2411ezrib-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/imagetext07.jpg)

Comment: @Martin A friend told me about the possibility to use js too ... if i can't do it with only css, i can prove others things :) Time to google ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Finally

After searching it with differents words for the same problem, I found an interesting article in [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/) about this.
Here i found this [codepen from Richard](https://codepen.io/strawstack/pen/LNXpGG).

```css
html, body{ background: grey; }
p{ margin: 0px; }

#clip{
  /*
  Ensure background is added first
  */  
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, rgba(222,112,6,0.2), #de7006),url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  
   background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  
  font-size: 28vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="clip">FIXED</p>
<p id="clip">FIXED</p>
<p id="clip">FIXED</p>
<p id="clip">FIXED</p>
<p id="clip">FIXED</p>
<p id="clip">FIXED</p>
```

Then, complementing this technique with my html and css, I have obtained the expected result:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400&display=swap');

/* Styles for the parents and child */
#block_top_menu{background:#6aa447;background:-moz-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);background:-webkit-gradient(left top,right top,color-stop(0%,#6aa447),color-stop(100%,#4d81bd));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);background:-o-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);background:linear-gradient(to right,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6aa447',endColorstr='#4d81bd',GradientType=1);display: flex;padding:0}
.sf-menu{background:transparent;border:none;box-shadow:0 0 #ccc;display:flex;width: inherit;margin:0}
.menu-li{border:none;float:none;margin:0;padding:10px 20px;}
.sf-menu > li:hover{background-color:#fff;}
.sf-menu > li > a{border:none;color:#fff;font: 400 20px Oswald;text-transform:none}

/* Magic */
.sf-menu > li:hover > a{
  background:#6aa447;background:-moz-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);background:-webkit-gradient(left top,right top,color-stop(0%,#6aa447),color-stop(100%,#4d81bd));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);background:-o-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(45deg,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);background:linear-gradient(to right,#6aa447 0%,#4d81bd 90%);
  
   background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  /*This last 3 lines are important for the magic*/
}

/* Others */
ul{list-style:none}
a{text-decoration: none;}
body{align-content:center;background-color:#f1f1f1;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;font-family:Oswald;height:90vh;justify-content:center;}
```

```html
<h1>Fill text with the gradient background of the parent</h1>
<div id="block_top_menu" class="full-width here-is-the-gradient">
    <ul class="sf-menu transparent">
        <li class="menu-li category transparent"><a href="/257-productos-medicos" title="Productos Médicos">Productos Médicos</a></li>
        <li class="menu-li category transparent"><a href="/257-productos-medicos" title="Productos Médicos">Productos Médicos</a></li>
      <li class="menu-li category transparent"><a href="/257-productos-medicos" title="Productos Médicos">Productos Médicos</a></li>
      <li class="menu-li category transparent"><a href="/257-productos-medicos" title="Productos Médicos">Productos Médicos</a></li>
      <li class="menu-li category transparent"><a href="/257-productos-medicos" title="Productos Médicos">Productos Médicos</a></li>
      <li class="menu-li category transparent"><a href="/257-productos-medicos" title="Productos Médicos">Productos Médicos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can see it in a [Full Page View at Codepen](https://codepen.io/v-alex/full/argNaO)

Thanks a lot to everyone who reads me and suggest me a solution or trick.

Greetings, V.Alex.

Comment: Remember to include the unprefixed `background-clip: text` as well.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.sitepoint.com/masking-in-the-browser-with-css-and-svg/ 
you will need to create a vector mask using SVG's.

warning:
css mask is not currently supported by IE
https://caniuse.com/#search=mask

codepen example:
https://codepen.io/antonietta/pen/zqpBEg

```
.masked {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    mask-image: url(https://s3-us-west-        
    2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/234228/trapeze.png),
    url(https://s3-us-west2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/234228/alpha-star.png);
    mask-position: center center, bottom right;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    mask-size: 350px 350px, 350px 350px;
}
```

Comment: I want to vote up this but i dunno how, thanks you for that information!

Comment: Cool, Im glad I could help. I think if you hit the up arrow next to the top of my response that will do it. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the descendant combinator? Like below?

```css
section {
  background: blue;
}

section .foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <p class=foo>
    World
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: It's more like to make the background-color of the 'World' color red and the text-color with the background color of the section, like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33PRj.jpg)